# GTK3 - Monitoring all signals emitted from a widget

Tags: gtk, gdk

Is there any way to monitor all signals emitted from a widget with GTK3? I know that the `event` signal is emitted before an event, but I'm not sure of the distinction between "event" and "signal" in GTK terminology - as this does not seem to capture all signals.

I know GDK has a function `gdk_set_show_events` but this mostly shows events which are sent to the window from the operating system. Is there a GTK3 equivalent?

Comment: Signals are GObject (ie. type system) functionality, which is not limited to Gtk. Events are Gtk terminology, and are just wrapped up messages from the display server. When a widget receives events, it will usually inform you about them using signals. Other things that are not directly the result of display server messages (eg. button clicks) are also transmitted using signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not built in function AFAIK, but I'm sure you can hack something together yourself:

Use [g_signal_lookup](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_lookup.html) to get all signal ids for a gtype. Then use [g_signal_add_emission_hook](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_add_emission_hook.html) on each signal of your instance to register a hook to be called whenever that particular signal is emitted. Inside the hook function, you're provided with the signal id via `*ihint`, from which [g_signal_query](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_query.html) should provide you with all the information you need to print debug messages. (I didn't test it, but it should work)

Note that this will unfortunately not work for signals defined with G_SIGNAL_NO_HOOKS.

Answer (score 0):

> Use *g_signal_lookup* to get all signal ids

It's a little more complicated than described. In order to use *g_signal_lookup*, you first need a signal-name. If you want to monitor every signal independent of the object-type, you first need to list all signals of the specific instance-type. This can be arranged by *g_signal_list_ids* for exactly one single *GType*. To get really ALL signals emitted on the instance, you need to iterate over all parent-types of this instance. You can do this by using *g_type_parent*.

I have build some utility-functions by myself, that provide this functionality for the same debugging purpose the question was intended. You can connect an Emission-Hook for all signals of a *GObject*-instance with [*gemu_glib_util_connect_to_all_signals*](https://github.com/Emanuesson/gemu-util/blob/master/gemu-glib-util.c) or connect an emission-Hook to a *GtkWidget*-instance and all its children with [*gemu_gtk_util_signal_connect_to_widget_children*](https://github.com/Emanuesson/gemu-util/blob/master/gemu-gtk-util.c).